# PHP Dynamic Class Loading w/ Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm using namespaces in PHP, and trying to load classes dynamically. My currently structure looks like this:

```
 class Bootstrap {

    protected $controller = 'home';

    protected $method = 'index';

    protected $params = [];

    function __construct($url) {
        $urlArray = $this->parseurl($url);
        if(file_exists('../app/http/controllers/' . $urlArray[0] . '.php'))
        {
            $this->controller = $urlArray[0];
            unset($urlArray[0]);
        }

        require_once '../app/http/controllers/' .  $this->controller . '.php';

        $this->controller = new Controllers\$this->controller;  

        var_dump($this->controller);
    }
    public function parseurl($url) {
        return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($url, '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

How do I make it so I can load the classes with this bootstrap function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line:

```
$this->controller = new Controllers\$this->controller;
```

is not valid PHP code.

If you need to instantiate classes using a dynamic class name, use an intermediate variable:

```
$className = 'Controllers\\' . $this->controller;
$this->controller = new $className();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$controller = 'Controllers\'.$this->controller;
$this->controller = new $controller();
```